# R POSIXlt Time Difference Format

Tags: r, time, formatting

I've got two POSIXlt times.
time_a and time_b.

When I type:

```
x = time_b - time_a
```

I get:

```
Time difference of 32.91667 mins
```

But when I type:

```
cat(x)
```

I get:

```
32.91667
```

How do I get the units for this number? I'd like to use this time difference as part of my chart title.

Comment: is x = time_b - time_a?

Comment: yes that's right sorry

Comment: have you tried difftime()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer.
It's the function:

```
format(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to caution people against using

```
x = time_a - time_b
```

to calculate time difference. I used this to calculate time difference for several data files and for some unknown reason it gave difference in **mins** for some data sets and in **secs** for some other. I had to spends hours to find this bug. The best way is to explicitly mention the units using this function-

```
as.numeric( difftime(time_a, time_b, units='secs') )
```

And save several hours of debugging